# Energy state of transistors

Tags: transistors, energy

Are there any energy states of transistors?  i.e. zero energy, high energy etc.

If that is possible, can't we employ the configurations of transistors such as storing memory as energy sources? That is, can't we create energy from memories?

Answer (score 1):

There are no energy states of transistors in the sense that energy is stored in a transistor, except for the tiny tiny amount of energy stored in the gate charge of a mosfet. Before you latch onto that as a storage device: your average household cat would probably be a more practical energy storage system (in the form of static charge).

Comment: @Wouter - and if that cat was in a sealed box how could we determine the energy level? Could it be that it is both charged and uncharged simultaneously? LOL